# I am wrapping my Icon under GestureDetector, but Icon doesn't change for onTap

Tags: flutter

I wanted to change my Icon from star_outlined to star when the Icon is tapped. While the gestures are being detected, the Icon is not changing. Does Icon remain constant?

```
class StarButton2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StarButton2State createState() => _StarButton2State();
}

class _StarButton2State extends State<StarButton2> {
  bool _color = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('onTap $_color');
        _color = !_color;
      },
      onLongPress: () {
        print('onLongPress');
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Icon(
          getData(_color),
          size: 216,
        ),
      ),
    );

IconData getData(_color) {
    return (_color ? Icons.star : Icons.star_rate_outlined);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `setState` on `onTap` function as you are trying to modify current state of the widget.

```
onTap: () {
    print('onTap $_color');
    setState(() {
      _color = !_color;
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use setState( () { } ) method while you tap.

Try replacing this:

```
onTap: () {
    print('onTap $_color');
    _color = !_color;
  },
```

with:

```
 onTap: () {
    print('onTap $_color');
    setState(() {
      _color = !_color;
    });
  },
```

You can read more about state control https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#managing-state here

Answer (score 1):

In order to see change you need to make use of  setState(() {});. Calling setstate notifies framework about internal state of this object has changed which results in rebuild of the particular state object.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: StarButton2(),
    );
  }
}

class StarButton2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StarButton2State createState() => _StarButton2State();
}

class _StarButton2State extends State<StarButton2> {
  bool _color = false;
  IconData getData(_color) {
    return (_color ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('onTap $_color');
          setState(() {
            _color = !_color;
          });
        },
        onLongPress: () {
          print('onLongPress');
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Icon(
            getData(_color),
            size: 216,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```